# I'm running into an issue with JSNI that I was hoping someone could help me with.

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am using an external JS file to generate QR codes 
The JS file is loading correctly, it just can't refer to that function. The specific error I am getting is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: qrcode is not defined
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLiwM.png)

Comment: https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs

Comment: Please provide a more specific title

Comment: include in your question the source code, instead of the image, indicating the exact line that generates the error

Comment: Its probably about the missing `$wnd`

Comment: provide more details

Comment: `code`
 public static native JavaScriptObject createQRCode(String id)/*-{
 var myQrcode= new QRCode($doc.getElementById(id),{
  text:www.baidu.com,
  width: 128,
        height: 128,
        colorDark : "#000000",
        colorLight : "#ffffff",
        correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
 });
 return myQrcode;
}-*/;     `code`

Comment: check the syntax http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html whether you followed or not?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest the tag **qrcode** could not be found. Is it in your HTML page as `id`? Also as suggested in the comment you need to do `new $wnd.QRCode(...` in `createQRCode`. Also you could pass the element found as argument to the latter method and do the search `getElementById` in GWT code as Java and use: `Document.getElementById`

Comment: Thanks,I have solved the problem ,because I forgot  '$wnd' in other postion